# Can I automate the migration of a static HTML site to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, migration, data-migration

I have recently started on a project that is a redesign of a static HTML website.  The previous site was handmade in Dreamweaver, and I don't think templates were used at all.  The old site has quite a bit of content, and manually copying and pasting the text from each old page into a new WordPress post will be very time consuming.

My initial idea was to extract the HTML inside the main area, rinse, repeat... But the content isn't enclosed in a unique div.  So, I can't just automate by pulling all the content between `<div id="content">` and `</div>` for example.  The pages also include images that I would need to transfer as well.

Is there a way I can automate, or at least improve, the migration from Static HTML to WordPress?

**Edit:** The old side does have some consistency in markup.  Each article can be simplified as having the following layout:

```
<tr><td class="title">Article Title</td></tr>
<tr><td width="80%"> Article content, with various formatting HTML</td></tr>
```

Granted, there is some additional HTML in there, but I think it is arbitrary.

Comment: Is there any consistent structure? Such as a header followed by nav followed by content? If so, you could parse it out into a tree and then extract it out into text files and go from there.

Comment: It does look like the structure is somewhat consistent.  I edited my original post to reflect that.